# generate javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException for unit test

Tags: spring-boot, exception, constraints, hibernate-validator

Springboot:  I got a mocked service and a method needs to return a javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException in order to properly unit test  the caller class.

I cannot seem to find a way to generate a ConstraintViolationException or ConstraintViolation for that matter in Hibernate Validators.

Is there some solution I missing out?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve exactly?

Because you can create a `ConstraintViolationException` without any violations in it if you just need the exception.

If you want a violation in it (you just have to pass a set of violations to the constructor), I would say you have several possibilities:

- You can simply implement `ConstraintViolation` as it's an interface and just put some code where you see fit.
- Otherwise, I would trigger a real validation (with `Validator.validate(myBean)`) and get the violations from there.
- You can use `ConstraintViolationImpl#forBeanValidation()` to forge a violation but it's an internal class so it might break in future versions of HV.

Comment: I need the exception to have an actual ConstrainViolation that has a field and a message. I will try Validator.validate and and that probably will help.